# Assign text to JLabels from ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, arraylist

I'm not actually sure how to ask this question because its very confusing. I have a java app that has a MVC structure, which gets data from a database. I retrieve  String ArrayList of data from a JDBC query.  It contains information about Competitors in a race (eg: Name, Race_no, Start_Time, Swim_Time, Bike_Time, Finish_Time etc).  The list size will vary week to week depending on the number of the competitors who raced that week.  I have no problem getting the data from the database, but when I pass the information to the controller to pass to the view, I am having trouble assigning the data to a JLabel.  So far the data is sent as one large array so I need to somehow split the array up in blocks of 12 (which is how many JLabels are required to be set for each competitor). I then set each of those 12 JLabels into its own JPanel ArrayList - then dynmically add to one JPanel for printing. My question is, how do I split the ArrayList to get the first 12, then the second lot of 12, etc.. I have tried doing a nested loop and set the size to 12, but of course that only gets the first 12 everytime. Maybe I need to store the data from the JDBC result set as something else.. I really need some guidance on this as have been stuck for days.

nb: I had this working as one large method in the data handler class, where I would use the while(rs.next()) to do all the work, but because of the MVC structure, I need to break the code up: This is the desired outcome:
[image]

**EDIT:**
I have implement this code which give me the desired output, but now having trouble assigning the JLabel variables with the data in the [j] loop:

```
<pre>
public void getRaceLabels()
    {
        ArrayList<String[]> raceLabels = dh.getRaceTimeLabels();

        //System.out.println(raceLabels);

        for (int i = 0; i < raceLabels.size(); i++)
        {

            String[] element = (String[]) raceLabels.get(i);
            //System.out.println(element);
            for (int j = 0; j < element.length; j++)
            {

                System.out.print(element[j]+" ,");
            }
            System.out.println("break");
        }
</pre>
```

Comment: Sonds like you should be using a JTable

Comment: yes, I could do a JTable but that is not the format the client wants. They ant to be able to give this info to the competitors after the race.

Comment: Okay, so it sounds more like you should be using JasperReports

Comment: @MadProgrammer I had a look at JasperReports but because all the other reports are just JTables I thought it was a bit overkill to implement this for one report. Also, our time frame is small and don't have time to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create yourself a POJO which represents the basic information you need for a single record.

When loading the data from the database, load this data into the POJO.

Now, for each panel, you just need to pass it a single object, meaning you can now get away with using a simple iterator instead

Comment: i ended up doing this and just iterated through to set the text of each JLabel. Thanks